# Why create Typescript as a separate language if it just outputs to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Couldn't Typescript simply be a JavaScript library to include with other libraries such as Angular? Is that what it is? Wouldn't being a JS library give greater support for outputting ES5 specific JS?

Comment: And what would that library do exactly?

Comment: The same exact thing I just wanted to know whether a library would be capable of doing precisely the same thing or if its not even possible and why

Comment: Typescript is more object oriented approach.
Also you can debug it  in IDE.

Comment: Well, Typescript does exactly nothing at runtime (in the browser or in Node). It is a language and has a compiler that outputs Javascript (and if you want, you can target ES5, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Librairies are runtime objects.

Typescript is a language that extends Javascript with new keywords, such as types.

These keywords need to be parsed and compiled/transpiled to Javascript **before** being executed by the Javascript engine.